# Memory issue with lm

Tags: r, memory, lm

I have a large data frame containing about 4 million rows and 15 variables. I'm trying to implement a model selection algorithm, which adds in a variable that results in the highest increase in the r-squared to the `lm` model.

The following code snippet is where my function fails due to the large data size. I tried `biglm` but still no luck. I use `mtcars` as an example here just to illustrate.

```
library(biglm)
library(dplyr)
data <- mtcars
y <- "mpg"
vars.model <- "cyl"
vars.remaining <- setdiff(names(data), c("mpg", "cyl"))

new.rsq <- sapply(vars.remaining, 
                  function (x) {
                      vars.test <- paste(vars.model, x, sep="+")
                      fit.sum <- biglm(as.formula(paste(y, vars.test, sep="~")), 
                                       data) %>% summary()
                      new.rsq <- fit.sum$rsq 
                  })
new.rsq
```

I'm not sure how exactly R handles the memory here, but the `biglm` output for my 4 million rows of data is extremely small (6.6 KB). I don't know how it accumulates to several GB when I wrapped it into `sapply`. Any tips on how to optimise this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that if all you want is the rsq you may be better off calculating it directly rather than fitting a linear model.

Comment: I've thought about that, but I'm not aware of a way to calculate rsq for multiple linear regression model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory usage goes up because each call to `biglm()` makes a copy of the data in memory. Since `sapply()` is basically a for loop, using `doMC` (or `doParallel`) allows to go through the loop with a single copy of the data in memory. Here is one possibility:

**EDIT**: As @moho wu pointed, parallel fitting helps, but not quite enough. Factors are more efficient than plain characters, so that helps too. Then `ff` can help even more as it keeps bigger data sets on the disk, rather than in memory. I updated the code below to make it a complete toy example using `ff` and `doMC`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pryr)

# toy data
df <- sample_n(mtcars, size = 1e7, replace = T)   
df$A <- as.factor(letters[1:5]) 

# get objects / save on disk
all_vars <- names(df) 
y <- "mpg"  
vars.model <- "cyl"
vars.remaining <- all_vars[-c(1:2)]
save(y, vars.model, vars.remaining, file = "all_vars.RData") 
readr::write_delim(df, path = "df.csv", delim = ";")

# close R session and start fresh

library(ff)
library(biglm)
library(doMC)
library(tidyverse)

# read flat file as "ff" ; also read variables
ff_df <- read.table.ffdf(file = "df.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE)
load("all_vars.RData") 

# prepare the "cluster"
nc <- 2 # number of cores to use
registerDoMC(cores = nc)

# make all formula
fo <- paste0(y, "~", vars.model, "+", vars.remaining)
fo <- modify(fo, as.formula) %>%
  set_names(vars.remaining)

# fit models in parallel
all_rsq <- foreach(fo = fo) %dopar% {
  fit <- biglm(formula = fo, data = ff_df)
  new.rsq <- summary(fit)$rsq
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. It still gives me the same error: `"cannot allocate vector of size 4.3 Gb"`

Comment: Is your data all numeric, or do you have factors?

Comment: about half are numeric, half are characters.

Comment: I got it working by converting all character variables to factors. Thanks for your answer. I'll check if it also works with my original script and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit to my problem is that I have a lot of character columns. It works fine after I change them all to factors using my original script.

```
data %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
```

@meriops' answer is also sound. Parallel processing might be something to consider if factorising your data frame doesn't solve the problem